# SQL query modification to get count of real return products

Tags: mysql, sql

Have few DB tables like `order_products` and `return_products`

return_products table columns:
    `id`, `rma_id`, `order_id`, `product_id`, `order_nr`, `comment`, `admin_comment`, `add_date`

order_products table columns:
    `id`, `order_id`,  `product_id`, `quantity`, `price`, `sum`

return products every row to each product, but order_products, have quantity column

and for now have SQL query like this to get orders depending on what product searching:

```
SELECT `id`, `saved` 
FROM `orders` 
WHERE 1 AND (`id` IN(
    SELECT `order_id` 
    FROM `order_products` 
    WHERE `product_id` IN (1,2,3,4,5)))
BY id DESC 
LIMIT 0, 30
```

And now need to check if order and product id is in return and return_products tables

i.e. 
if searching product with `id` 2 in orders I need to check if that product exists in return table, what count and if count equals to order_products quantity, dont need to show that order in list, but if return quantity is less than order_products quantity than need to show (order_products.quantity - COUNT(return_products))

Comment: Please provide sample data. What is return table, which of return_products.order_id or order_nr refers to sales order?

Answer (score 0):

No relation to order table there, but you have the logic for the order_products / return_products quantity comparison.

```
select op.product_id, op.quantity, count(rp.id)
from order_products op
left join return_products rp on rp.product_id = op.product_id --maybe need to join on order_id too ? Not really clear
group by op.product_id, op.quantity
--where op.product_id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
having op.quantity <> count(rp.id)
```